# Output post thumbnail (add class)

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm using the following to output the post thumbnail as a marker on a map.

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, array( 100, 100), true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
```

But, I want to add a class to the thumbnail.

I tried `array('class' => 'your-class-name')`
but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `wp_get_attachment_image()` instead if you want to set a class property.

Example:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image(
    get_post_thumbnail_id(), 
    array(100, 100), 
    true, 
    array('class' => 'your-class-name')
);

//returns the HTML for the attachment
echo $image;
```

The above function returns the HTML `img` tag:

`<img src="http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg" class="your-class-name"/>`

You can see the difference between functions here:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/